# Looking for a better way to wait for an element to appear and disappear

Tags: java, logging, selenium-webdriver

*I have a working solution, but I am hoping there is a better way.*

In automating a website, there are many places where a spinner is shown to tell the user that a process is running. The div is added and removed from the DOM as needed; as opposed to a class change or setting display:none.

When I first starting building the automation framework, I had a simple wait for the element to no longer be there: numberOfElementsToBe equal to 0. But I kept having timing issues: it was taking too long for the spinner to appear in the first place so the code would assume everything was done, continue on, and fail because the page was not ready yet.

To combat this, I added a try/catch to first look/wait for the spinner to appear for 2 seconds. Then, whether the code sees the spinner or not, it waits for it to disappear.

```
try {
        quickWait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By.className(identifier), 0));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Nope
    }
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By.className(identifier), 0));
}
```

This way, I catch all situations:

- Normal - Wait for spinner, it shows up normally, then wait for it
  to go away
- Slow - Wait for spinner, it takes a second to show up but
  is still caught by the first wait, and then wait for it to go away
- Fast - Wait for spinner, but the operation was so fast that the spinner has already come and gone. So the code waits for the spinner for two seconds and doesn't see it, so it falls to the catch which does nothing, and then waits for the spinner to go away (which it already has) so immediately continues on.

All this is fine except for all the "fast" situations. Since the wait fails, it throws a WARNING in the running console log (Not the browser console). This makes diagnosing issues a pain as I have to wade through a bunch of WARNINGs trying to find the real issue.

- I don't want to turn off all warnings as there could be important info in other areas.
- This is a **runtime** warning so @SuppressWarnings is not working.

So does anyone have any suggestions/alternate methods for handling "wait for situation to exist/wait for it to stop" situations that wouldn't throw out a ton of useless warnings? **I'm looking for either a "Do this instead" method or a way to stifle runtime WARNING messages for a single method.**

---

**Note:** The timing of the spinner is variable. Sometimes it's so quick it is barely a flicker on the screen, and other times it takes a second to even show on the screen. The tests should not be so brittle that a mistimed spinner causes it to fail. It is only used as a signal that the results are available.

Comment: What is printing the WARNING to the log? I've never seen Selenium print things to the browser console.

Comment: Not the browser console, the console the test is running in. Here is an example: --- Dec 15, 2017 1:12:41 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElements
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElements(By.cssSelector: xxxx)
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?

Comment: @MivaScott Maybe this is a long shot as never done much logging api. The logging is coming from the logger in "ExpectedConditions.java" findElement and findElements method. You could try and get hold of the logger using the LogManager.getLogger(ExpectedConditions.class.getName()) method in the try block before you call the EC. Set the level off this to OFF using logger.setLevel(Level.OFF). Add a finally block and switch this back to WARNING. You might need checks for null etc...